# Coding Style for User defined Exception in java

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns, styles

I'm working on a java project. while browsing the existing code of User defined Exception class, i came across a the code written like below:

```
public final class ApplicationException extends RuntimeException {

public static void enforce(final String message) {
    throw new ApplicationException(message);
}
private ApplicationException(final String message) {
    super(message);
}
}
```

and whenever i have to throw an exception within code, I write

```
ApplicationException.enforce("exception message here");
```

I wanted to know is this some coding style or pattern i.e. enclosing the creation and throw of Exception in a public static method and calling that method whenever we want to throw exception?

What may be the reason developer chose this way to throw exception? why not directly write
        `throw new ApplicationException("some message");` whenever required.

what is the gain using that style?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It encapsulates the `new` keyword in a method, which might be seen as making the user-defined exception into a kind of [simple factory](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/240351/51948).

This might have advantages for maintenance and/or testing later, since you just change the implementation of the `enforce` method and client code calling it will change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any specific reason for it and the pattern is not commonly used in Java projects.

He probably just used such code to look nicely.